# The equals sign (=) in android assigns a reference

Tags: android, textview

Here's the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fortesting"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and this is the main.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val newValue = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.fortesting)
        newValue.text = "new text here."
    }
}
```

As you can see, I assign `fortesting` to an arbitrary variable and change its value. Suddenly, this changes the value of `fortesting`, also. I reckon `newValue` is a reference, but I know you must use the box operator `::` to obtain a reference. This is strange. Could you please shed some light on this.

Comment: I think you're confused.  You aren't assigning forestring to anything in the code you show.  For the rest-  the :: operator isn't needed to get a reference, in Kotlin all variables are references-  objects don't exist in anything other than references.  You're so confused I don't even know how to help you here.

Comment: in Kotlin all variables and values are reference. When you say use :: to obtain a reference, which language do you mean?

Comment: suppose I have this code `var name = 2; var namecopy = name; namecopy = 3; prinln(name)`. The result of `println` is still `2`. As you see, I can't change `name` through `namecopy`

Comment: I have found out. Class types work differently from primitive types.

Comment: @ntos That's because you're assigning a value.  If you were using objects you'd get the same result there-  you're overwriting what namecopy references.  `val a=Foo(); val b=a;  b=Foo(); println(a) would also print out the original a and not b.  Nopw if you called a function that changes a property, like b.name="newname" instead of overwriting the value with =, then both a and b would be changed, because they refer to the same object.